# Blazor - Change navbar text and color on the Register and Login Pages

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have already done: *Add > New Scaffolded Item* and added the Identity pages to my project. I have made some changes to the body of the Login and Register pages with no issues. However, I am struggling with finding exactly where in the code the Navbar is so that I can make changes to it as well.

What I'm wanting to change is the Navbar color and the text "My Application":

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the navbar under Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

Comment: I'm a goof. I kept looking at Pages/Account/Manage/_Layout.cshtml since it was with the ones I added. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @Sarah Cox Perfectly understandable.  The whole scaffolding thing is kind of lame IMO.  I know they have reasons, but the Blazor experience is kind of "Wow. . . I can just do this?  Nice.  Now, let's add a User system. . . ohhhhhhh. . . THIS still. :("